# How to add digital signature to PDF file with Chilkat Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi, pdf, chilkat

I am testing the creation of a detached digital signature in PDF file using Chilkat for Delphi DLL. So far I have managed to sign the file but instead of adding a digital signature it certified the file. I am using the examples provided by Chilkat for signing. In them it can be seen that they too certify the file. The only time a digital signature is added to the file is when one had already existed.

Is there a way to specify signing option - certification or adding a digital signature?

[Chilkat example link](https://www.example-code.com/delphiDll/sign_pdf_simple.asp)

Comment: What do Chilkat themselves say about this?

Comment: The problem will be resolved in the next version